# How to kill thread which is calculating function from external library

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I am using external library to find minimum of function(optimization). Sometimes it demands a lot of time and I want to stop calculations (for example by clicking button). So I perform optimization in another thread. All examples I have seen do something like this(in subclass of `QThread`):

```
void run(){
    for(int i=0;i<100000;i++){
        if(!flag) break;
        //do something
     }
}
```

And when flag is set to `false` by main thread second thread stops. The problem is that I cannot put such flag into external library. However I provide reference to function which is to be mininize so that every iteration the function will be called. So I have put flag into that function:

```
double function(double x){
    if(!flag)  ;//here I should kill thread
    return x*x*x+2*x*x+7*x+7;
}
```

So how to kill that thread?

Comment: Can you show the code you are using right now as an [mcve]?

Comment: What external library are you using? Provide a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues:

1. If the code that runs inside of the thread has allocated any resources (memory, file handles, ...), they will leak if you `QThread::terminate` the worker thread.
2. It is not clear whether your optimization library has a set way to tell it that the iteration is to be terminated. If the library is under your control, you should simply have it stop iterating upon getting a `NaN` from the function.

The flag you're looking for is `QThread::isInterruptionRequested`. To set it, invoke `requestInterruption()` on the thread. There are many possible ways your library could be forced to terminate the iteration. You could try the following:

- Return a `std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN()` from the function:

  ```
  double function(double x){
    return isInterruptionRequested()
      ? std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN() 
      : x*x*x+2*x*x+7*x+7;
  }
  ```
- Return a constant from the function.

  ```
  double function(double x){
    return isInterruptionRequested()
      ? 0.0 : x*x*x+2*x*x+7*x+7;
  }
  ```
- Switch the function to have a global minimum around the most recent value:

  ```
  class MyThread : public QThread {
    bool m_wasInterrupted;
    double m_minimum;
    double function(double x){
      if (!isInterruptionRequested())
        return x*x*x+2*x*x+7*x+7;
      if (!m_wasInterrupted) {
        m_minimum = x;
        m_wasInterrupted = true;
      }
      return abs(x-m_minimum) : 
    }
    void run() {
      m_wasInterrupted = false;
      ...
    }
  };
  ```
- Force an exception:

  ```
  class end_iteration_exception : public std::exception {};

  class MyThread : public QThread {
    ...
    double function(double x){
      if (isInterruptionRequested()) throw end_iteration_exception();
      return x*x*x+2*x*x+7*x+7;
    }
    void run() {
      try {
        ...
      } catch (const end_iteration_exception&) {
        // we've been interrupted
      }
    }
  };
  ```

The optimization library, if written in C++, should be taking a functor, and thus you'd pass it `std::bind(&MyThread::function, this)` from within `run()`.

If it doesn't, and instead has a C api that takes only a function pointer, then it should offer a version that lets you pass a constant parameter as a second argument to the function:

```
double findMinimum(double (*fun)(double, void*), void * param) {
  ...
  double val = fun(x, param);
  ...
  return x;
}
```

Your function then would take that 2nd parameter to mean a thread instance:

```
class MyThread {
  static double function(double x, void* p){
    auto self = reinterpret_cast<MyThread*>(p);
    return self->isInterruptionRequested()
      ? 0.0 : x*x*x+2*x*x+7*x+7;
  }
  void run() {
    ...
    auto x = findMinimum(&function, this);
    ...
  }
  ...
};
```

If it doesn't even do that, then you can't but resort to global state:

```
class MyThread;
namespace {
MyThread * threadState { nullptr };
}

class MyThread : public QThread {
  ...
  void run() {
    threadState = this;
    ...
    threadState = nullptr;
  }
  static double function(double x) {
    return threadState->isInterruptionRequested() ? ...;
  }
};
```

Comment: I have simplified my problem to make example more clear. Actually it is multidimensional optimization and argument in function is a vector. I also provide functions (to the library) which calculates gradient vector and hessian matrix. So now when flag is turned Instead of calculating gradient I just return zero vector. It works!

Comment: @lnk Great. I'm glad that a simple workaround like that has worked.

Answer (score 1):

[`QThread`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qthread.html) has a function `terminate()` that can be used to cancel the thread.  That is probably a bad idea, because it would mean that objects with automatic storage duration created by the thread would not be cleaned up.

You can try throwing an exception, and catching it in the toplevel function of your thread.  However, the external library that control passes through must be exception-safe for that to work, of course.

Failing that, the possible solutions become more hacky: you can try returning special values from your function, in the hope that the external library will cleanly abort (or gracefully end) the iteration.  Candidates for such values are `0.0`, `-std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity()`, `std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN()`.

Comment: @KubaOber QThread::terminate is not recomended, and is very bad practice, because it terminates thread in random position, no resorces are freed.

Comment: @marcinj Sure the resources will leak, but what else can you do? Nothing really. It'd probably be easier if the calculations were done in a sub-process that can be terminated without worrying about resource leaks.

Comment: @KubaOber Thanks, noted.  No Idea why I overlooked that the first time I looked at the docs.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is little you can do. If you dont want to kill/terminate that thread - which is good, you might at best abandon such thread and allow it to end. This is true if your function does not allow for cancelling its work.

You might also try doing your work in smaller multiple batches, but it also depends on how your function works.

There might be some platform specific techniques which might be of some help. For example exception injection, you might read in this article http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/71529/Exception-Injection-Throwing-an-Exception-in-Other that under windows it should be possible to inject an exception to thread, this way it should be possible to gracefully (with calling destructors) finish you external library function.

Answer (score 0):

One way to kill a thread on Unix would be to set a signal disposition to this thread and send a signal. Thread will see a signal and can exit. This is not scalable, though, as you can only have one disposition per signal, meaning, that every thread you run will have to respond to a specific signal.